# Как возращать разное значение LocalDateTime.now() при каждом get-запросе используя scope=request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Можете-ли подсказать верно ли я реализовал логику возращения текущей даты при каждом обращении с помощью get-запроса?Знаю ,что можно просто возращать в методе напрямую LocalDAteTime.now(),но задача сделать эту с помощью scope=request.

**class Endpoint**

```
@RestController
public class Endpoint {

@Autowired
private TimeGenerator TIME;

@GetMapping("/time")
private LocalDateTime getTimeLocal(){
    return TIME.getTime();
}
```

**class TimeGenerator**

```
@Getter
public class TimeGenerator {
    private LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

**class Config**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public TimeGenerator requestScopedBean() {
        return  new TimeGenerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: почему бы поле просто методом не заменить? `private LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();` => `public LocalDateTime getTime(){ return ... }` ?

Comment: @tym32167 учту. А с точки зрения правильности реализации верно-ли сделано?

Comment: я не супер спец в java, но я бы сервис для получения времени делал бы синглтоном, чтобы этот класс не создавался на каждый запрос.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем тут `scope=request`. Обычно так делают, когда хотят, чтоб во время обработки одного запроса разные компоненты всегда получали одно и то же время. Если именно это нужно - то эта реализация неправильная.

Comment: @RomanKonoval а можно ли ссылку на что-то подобное,хотелось бы посмотреть пример,Если не затруднит?

Comment: Я погорячился и недоглядел. Эта реализация именно так и будет работать. Если заменить методом, то как раз будет неправильно. Так как сейчас время иницииализируется один раз при создании бина.

Comment: @RomanKonoval в такой постановке задача сводится не к `дай текущее время` , а к `дай время начала запроса` - я бы для этого получил время один раз и передавал бы как параметр в остальные классы/методы

Comment: @tym32167 если использование бина с `scope=request` это условие задачи, то тут ничего не поделаешь. В простых случаях передавать параметром будет ок. В более менее сложном проекте передавать параметр по всему дереву вызовов - это может быть слишком неудобно. Все классы начинают знать об этом времени, даже если оно им совершенно не нужно. Бин в контексте запроса с внедрением в бины, которым это время нужно - самое оно.

Comment: @RomanKonoval ох, это интересно. Хотел бы я поглядеть на пример. Просто читая ваш комментарий, я бы задался вопросом к проектированию системы, если бы у меня классы принимали информацию, которая им не нужна.